# Checking multiple fields in firebase with flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

```
.collection(collectionName)
                      .where("from", isEqualTo: widget.from + "@gmail.com")
                      .where("to", isEqualTo: widget.user.email)
                      .where("from", isEqualTo: widget.user.email)
                      .where("to", isEqualTo: widget.from + "@gmail.com")
                      .snapshots(),
```

this is my issue I need to add more where clause but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: what does debug console shows when you try to subscribe with this stream?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to fetch the data if your from and to email matches then you can use logical && or logical or || based on your requirement

```
.collection(collectionName)
                      .where("from", isEqualTo: widget.from + "@gmail.com",  
                             && "to", isEqualTo: widget.to + "&gmail.com")
                      .snapshots(),
```